# How to perform a this kind of Distinct operation with LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following `foreach` loop:

```
List<WorkingJournal> workingJournals = new List<WorkingJournal>();
foreach (WorkRoster workRoster in workRosters)
{
    bool exists = workingJournals.Any(workingJournal => workingJournal.ServicePlan.Id == workRoster.ServicePlan.Id
                                      && workingJournal.Nurse.Id == workRoster.Nurse.Id
                                      && workingJournal.Month == workRoster.Start.Month
                                      && workingJournal.Year == workRoster.Start.Year);

    if (exists == false)
    {
                WorkingJournal workingJournal = new WorkingJournal
                {
                    ServicePlan = workRoster.ServicePlan,
                    Nurse = workRoster.Nurse,
                    Month = workRoster.Start.Month,
                    Year = workRoster.Start.Year
                };

                workingJournals.Add(workingJournal);
    }
}
```

I started writing:

```
from workRoster in workRosters
select new WorkingJournal
                {
                    ServicePlan = workRoster.ServicePlan,
                    Nurse = workRoster.Nurse,
                    Month = workRoster.Start.Month,
                    Year = workRoster.Start.Year
                };
```

But now I am stuck with the comparison that produces distinct WorkingJournals.
I have a feeling that a group by clause should be here but I'm not sure how it should be done.

Comment: Put it all in brackets then do `.Distinct()`.

Comment: Is this Linq to Sql or Linq to Objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have proper `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations inside your class, you can simply invoke `Distinct()`.

```
var result = workRosters.Select(...).Distinct();
```

On the chance you do not have such implementations, you can define an `IEqualityComparer<WorkingJournal>` implementation. This will have you defining `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods for the `T` that can then be used by a dictionary or hashset and can also be used in overloads of `Distinct()` in Linq.

```
class JournalComparer : IEqualityComparer<WorkingJournal>
{
    public bool Equals(WorkingJournal left, WorkingJournal right)
    {
         // perform your equality semantics here
    }

    public int GetHashCode(WorkingJournal obj)
    {
         // return some hash code here.
         return obj.ServicePlan.GetHashCode();
    }
}

var comparer = new JournalComparer(); // implements the interface 
var result = workRosters.Select(r => new WorkingJournal { ... }).Distinct(comparer);
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming LINQ to objects:

```
(from workRoster in workRosters
 select new WorkingJournal
            {
                ServicePlan = workRoster.ServicePlan,
                Nurse = workRoster.Nurse,
                Month = workRoster.Start.Month,
                Year = workRoster.Start.Year
            }).Distinct();
```

Note that for this to work you need `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implemented for the `WorkingJournal` object. If not, see Anthony's answer: [How to perform a this kind of Distinct operation with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726588/how-to-perform-a-this-kind-of-distinct-operation-with-linq/7726641#7726641)

---

If it's LINQ to SQL you could group by the new expression, then select the group key:

```
from workRoster in workRosters
group workRoster by new WorkingJournal
            {
                ServicePlan = workRoster.ServicePlan,
                Nurse = workRoster.Nurse,
                Month = workRoster.Start.Month,
                Year = workRoster.Start.Year
            } into workRosterGroup
select workRosterGroup.Key;
```

Comment: so why did the original coder compared it to the work roster?

Comment: Your code adds all work rosters to the new list, providing it's not already in the list. My code effectively adds everything, then removes duplicates, which is the same thing.